# Print pdf file displayed inside iframe to printer

Tags: javascript, html

How can I print a pdf file displayed inside iframe directly to printer from Firefox/IE?

The following code works in chrome/opera well,but not in IE and Firefox.

```js
function printIframe(objFrame) {
    objFrame.focus();
    objFrame.print();
}
```

```html
<iframe  id="pdfreport" name="pdfreport" src="1.pdf" width="100%;" height="80%">
</iframe>
<button type="button" style="float: right" name="btnprint" onclick='printIframe(pdfreport);'>Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using php print command instead of printing contents of iframe,I used print command that directly print pdf file to printer.

`exec(" \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe\" /p  test.pdf ")`

This is the command used.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
 function printPage() { 
        print();
 }

 function printIframe(objFrame) {
         var ifr = document.frames ? document.frames[objFrame] : document.getElementById(objFrame);
         var ifW = ifr.contentWindow || ifr;
         ifr.focus();
         ifW.printPage();
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: IE,showing invalid calling object error and in firefox TypeError: ifr is null is shown

Comment: what is your vesion IE ?